# how we can see which service run in particular port in Linux using command?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, networking, service, port

like i want too see on **port no. xx:xx** which service are running or **all port** with all service run on any Linux machine it can be possible on **local machine** as well **other machine** [ *using IP address* ] of network in LAN area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your local server you can use for example the ss command with the following options: `ss -tulpn`

For a remote server, probably you first need to expand or understand what you are trying to achieve: if you need to check all ports exposed to other servers on the network you can use nmap like: `nmap -Pn`

Otherwise, if you want the same output of ss for a remote server the best way is to SSH to the other server and launch the ss command from there.

Comment: Glad it helped, don't forget to accept the answer and mark your question as solved :)